# Typescript module not found errors when compiling

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

When I compile typescript, I get errors like below. I run it using `webpack-dev-server`.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'i18n' in ...
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../moment' in ...
```

However in the code where I import them like this

```
import * as i18n from "i18n";
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

And there is no underline meaning the static checker determines it is found.

tsconfig.js

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "module": "ES2020",
        "target": "ES2020",
        "lib": [
            "ES2020"
        ],
        "allowJs": false,
        "alwaysStrict": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./src"
    ]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/bot.ts',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts'],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bot.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
};
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "npm dist/bot",
        "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
        "build": "webpack --mode production",
        "lint": "npx eslint . --ext .ts"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/i18n": "^0.8.6",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.7",
        "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
        "@types/node": "^14.0.26",
        "@types/node-schedule": "^1.3.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.7.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.7.0",
        "chokidar": "^3.4.1",
        "eslint": "^7.5.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jest": "^23.18.2",
        "ts-loader": "^8.0.1",
        "typescript": "^3.9.7",
        "webpack": "^4.20.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
        "node-schedule": "^1.3.2",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "discord.js": "^12.2.0",
        "i18n": "^0.10.0",
        "moment": "^2.27.0"
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which editor are you using? Sometimes, with VS Code, I get strange errors and just restart the IDE. 
Did you also do a `npm install`?

Comment: I tried npm install and am using VS Code.

Comment: Can you try to add the following inside "compilerOptions":
`"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],`

Comment: sorry, didn't work

Comment: Do I need to put them in the `include` array?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to restart typescript on VS Code.

A way to do this is to

1. go to 'Go' in the menus,
2. select 'Go to File'
3. Type the greater than symbol, (>)
4. Then type 'TypeScript: Restart TS server'
5. Press enter

You might be able to use short-cuts to get to menu items quicker
Control-shift-P, to skip to the step 4.

Comment: I added my webpack config too above.

Comment: @omega check your package.json file if it is there

Comment: i added my package.json above and I did `npm install` to ensure all packages got installed.

Comment: it could be the version, you could try downgrading to the one before, that is, 2.26.0, maybe also remove the ^ or it will keep going back to the latest. npm install moment@2.26.0 for the moment